# How to unlock a button by selecting an item from the list?

Tags: angular

I wanted and still want to do so that when you click on one item from the list the button is unlocked, and so that somehow the selected item is highlighted in color. Here is my workpiece that does not work(
Tell me how you can implement this action.

html:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-content table-responsive ">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a (click)="SelectedPost(post?.post_id)">
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr  *ngFor="let post of posts">
                <td>{{post.name}} </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!selectedPost" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
...
export class PostComponent  implements ModalComponent<any> {

  posts: Array<Post>;
  selectedPost = null;

  constructor(
    public dialog: DialogRef<any>, 
    public authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private servPost: SprPostService
  ) { 
    this.sprPosts = new Array<Post>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPosts();
  }

  private loadPosts() {
    this.servPost.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
  }

  SelectedPost(PostId) {
    this.selectedPost = this.posts.find(el => {
      return el.post_id === PostId
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: why can't you bind your tr with (click) binding

Comment: @Avij If I knew how to do this, I would definitely tie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of posts will be traverse through *ngFor. Each tr will display each record of your list. So no of tr will be your posts list.
  You have to apply selectedPost() function on tr, Because on tr you will get post instance of posts list. Refer below code:

```
<a>
    <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr  *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="SelectedPost(post?.post_id)">
                <td>{{post.name}} </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </a>
```

Now you will get selected post. Other things you have already did.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click event to whatever element in Angular. You can assign a function to the event, which should assign the post `selectPost()`.

```
<tr  *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <td (click)="selectPost(post)">{{post.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The function (in your component.ts) is simple, you use the post as function argument:

```
public selectPost(postToSelect: Post){
  this.selectedPost = postToSelect;
}
```

(You can set the selectedPost directly too, like this: `(click)="selectedPost = post"`. But its better to put it in a function)